# Understand S3 cost at folder level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am planning for a use case wherein which my S3 bucket is used by 10 different users. All these users has separate folders within this bucket, to where they'll store their files. Now I want to know how much storage (and there by the cost) does each of these users use . I know there's cost allocation tag, but that's to be used at the bucket level. Is there anyway that I can get to know this cost, maybe using lambda script or any other way? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: S3 doesn't actually *have* folders. The console and some clients will treat `/` in object keys *like* a folder, but they're not actually folders behind the scenes.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes I understand that. I have this use case for some customers, which I am worried how to tackle it. I can't assign them each separate bucket because of the hard limit on bucket numbers within an account.

Comment: You said your use case is 10 users. AWS permits up to 1,000 buckets in an account. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: @ceejayoz, Ok, I have asked you from a real time perspective. If those users are my customers, then there might be case where I could have more than 1000 customers also. So, thats not a possible solution then..

Comment: You could use S3's ListObjects API with a prefix; you could store details about the file in a database somewhere when you process the upload; you could just bill them enough to cover an average amount of usage and go after the occasional customer who abuses it by uploading terabytes. Various options are avail.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. What are the other options, if you have anything in mind?

Comment: Maybe not exactly a solution, but you can allow object-level CloudTrail on the s3 bucket and then make some reporting based on the logs.